# Codeigniter URI issue...No URI present. Default controller set

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have an issue with my codeigniter application deployed on an EC2 instance on Amazon.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://XX.XX.XXX.107/';
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

This is my route.php (without any particular rule)

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Actually if I call http://xx.xx.xxx.107/ it correctly show my first page (it loads my default controller Home.php and shows home.php view).
But if I call for example http://52.59.107.107/index.php/Home/sign_in_form, instead of showing sign_in form view, it shows again home view.

I enabled log, and this is what I get

```
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Config Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Hooks Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> UTF-8 Support Enabled
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Utf8 Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> URI Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> No URI present. Default controller set.
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Router Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Output Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Security Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Global POST, GET and COOKIE data sanitized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Input Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Language Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Loader Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Helper loaded: file_helper
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Helper loaded: form_helper
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Helper loaded: url_helper
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Database Driver Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Session: Class initialized using 'files' driver.
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> XML-RPC Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Controller Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Model Class Initialized
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Form Validation Class Initialized
DEBUG - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Session class already loaded. Second attempt ignored.
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> File loaded: /var/www/core_ci/application/views/header.php
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> File loaded: /var/www/core_ci/application/views/home.php
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> File loaded: /var/www/core_ci/application/views/footer.php
INFO - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Final output sent to browser
DEBUG - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> Total execution time: 0.1061
```

As you can see in the log, I'm getting **DEBUG - 2016-08-08 15:43:25 --> No URI present. Default controller set**., even if I'm calling this url http://xx.xx.xxx.107/index.php/Home/sign_in_form

Here some data about my server:

```
PHP Version 5.5.35
System  Linux ip-xx-x-x-xxx 4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Apr 27 19:28:52 UTC 2016 x86_64
Build Date  May 2 2016 23:29:10
Server API  FPM/FastCGI
```

Here the vhost Apache file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  # Leave this alone. This setting tells Apache that
  # this vhost should be used as the default if nothing
  # more appropriate is available.

  ServerName default:80

  # REQUIRED. Set this to the directory you want to use for
  # your “default” site files.

  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  # Optional. Uncomment this and set it to your admin email
  # address, if you have one. If there is a server error,
  # this is the address that Apache will show to users.

  #ServerAdmin you@example.com

  # Optional. Uncomment this if you want to specify
  # a different error log file than the default. You will
  # need to create the error file first.

  #ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/logs/error_log

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
  DirectoryIndex /index.php index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there anyone that can tell me where I'm failing?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

Home.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Home extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('Home_model');
                $this->load->model('Users_model');
                $this->load->model('Credit_model');
                $this->load->library('form_validation');
                $this->load->library('language');
                $this->load->library('alerts');
                $this->load->library('session');
                $this->load->helper('url');
//        $this->load->helper('captcha');
        }

public function test()
{
        print_r('my test method');
}
```

As you can see I prepared for simplicity a test method in Home controller.
If I call http://xx.xx.xxx.107/index.php/Home/test I get the same log sequence and it shows the home view instead of printing my raw data.

It seems that as it is not able to get correct URi, it run default controller.

Comment: Can you show your HomeController.php code?

Comment: @MaxGilbert see part of the Home controller in the updates

Comment: Thanks for the update. The application definitely lives in the www/public_html folder, there is no sub directories going on?

Comment: yes it lies in /var/www/html directory; then I moved /application and /system directories out of documentroot and obviously edited the index.php to set application and system path accordingly

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of research and looking inside httpd service log I found the solution

In vhost file I substituted this line of code

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/var/www/html/$1
```

with these ones

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
        # 2.4.10+ can proxy to unix socket
        # SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/"

        # Else we can just use a tcp socket:
        SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```